# how retreive the soapFault from provider and continue route camel with this string fault in body?

Tags: apache-camel, camel-cxf

i use Quarkus 3.4.3 & Camel 4.0.0, and i have a CXF Endpoint. But when receiver a response SoapFault, i lose the response with this soapFault.

i need keep this soapFault string and use it for next steps of my route.

i have try, many Interceptors , but not work. The one work it is on the OnException(SaopFault.class), create .process retreive some piece of soapFault String and reconstruct all SOAPMessage ..but it is very bad.

it is not possible to do other way with interceptor inFaultInterceptor save the XML (soapFault response) and setBody with this ?  easely ? without all recreate message...

thanks.

This is bad, because i dont know many details have the response ...

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    SoapFault faultCXF = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, SoapFault.class);
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

                    SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
                    SOAPEnvelope envelope = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
                    SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
                    SOAPFault fault = body.addFault();
                    fault.setFaultCode(faultCXF.getFaultCode());
                    fault.setFaultString(faultCXF.getReason());
                    Detail detail = fault.addDetail();
```

Comment: in other work, i want keep PAYLOAD soapFault and continu route.

Comment: I have already tried in interceptors,
FaultOutInterceptor; FIStaxOutInterceptor;

And the only examples are with LoggingOutInterceptor and it's deprecated

public void handleFault(Message message) {
            LOGGER.info("///*****///// start LoggingOutInterceptorExtend");
            //super.handleMessage(message);

public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            LOGGER.info("///*****///// start LoggingOutInterceptorExtend");
            //super.handleMessage(message);

but i have nothing in my content...

Comment: I found it, and so I come to bring my solution to the community.

CxfEndpoint, it is necessary to add an interceptor of type 'AbstractSoapInterceptor' which will save stream into a variable.

FaultOutInterceptorExtend faultOutInterceptorExtend = new 
FaultOutInterceptorExtend(Phase.RECEIVE);

cxfServiceClient.getInFaultInterceptors().add(faultOutInterceptorExtend);

for interceptor impl. see next comment. (fk characters left :( )

Comment: The Interceptor into handleMessage :
CachedOutputStream out = soapMessage.getContent(CachedOutputStream.class);
byte[] originalMessage = new byte[0];
try {
  originalMessage = IOUtils.readBytesFromStream(out.getInputStream());
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
fault = new String(originalMessage);
soapMessage.remove(Message.RESPONSE_CODE);
soapMessage.put(Message.RESPONSE_CODE, (Integer) 200);
soapMessage.getExchange().put("faultProvider", fault);

After you can go to OnException(SoapFault.class)

Comment: Add un .process with :
'code'Message cxfMessage = exchange.getIn().getHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_MESSAGE, Message.class);
if (cxfMessage != null) {
                            String faultProvider = (String) cxfMessage.getExchange().get("faultProvider");
                            // read message from camel context
                            org.apache.camel.Message inMessage = exchange.getIn();
                            inMessage.setBody(faultProvider);